# Approach for validating 1 of n fields must be valid?

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc

What's the preferred approach for validating that at least one of fieldA, fieldB, or fieldC is valid using a Spring 3 validator? In other words, any 2 of the fields can be invalid, as long as the third is not.

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=49245) poses almost the same question. The solution there is to add the following to `validation-rules.xml`:

```
<validator name="requiredif" 
    classname="org.springmodules.validation.commons.Fi eldChecks"
    method="validateRequiredIf" 
    methodParams="java.lang.Object, org.apache.commons.validator.ValidatorAction, org.apache.commons.validator.Field, org.springframework.validation.Errors, org.apache.commons.validator.Validator"
    msg="errors.required">
</validator>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use JSR-303 Bean Validation ([see example here](http://www.earldouglas.com/node/40)).  Simply annotate the fields that you need to validate.

Comment: Indeed I did, and Spring's 303 support is my "preferred approach for validating".  My example doesn't cover this specific use case, but that's why it's an example and not a solution to this particular question.